# Why does the clean string function not prevent html links from being submitted in comments field

Tags: php, validation

Here is my form processing script. However I still get html links posted in my comments box. Can someone please explain how the clean string function works(or rather why it doesn't work)?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$email_to = "myemail address here";
$email_subject = "Request from my Website";
$email_header = "my email address here"; 
$name = $_POST['name']; // required 
$company = $_POST['phone']; // required 
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$demowhat = $_POST['message']; // required
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);                }

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email Address: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($demowhat)."\n";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From:'.$email_header."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can not yet comment this will go as an answer.

The function ***clean_string()*** is not a predefined library function, so from what I can see you search for any of the mail elements and replace them with nothing "".

```
function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); //an array strings

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);  //str_replace(find,replace,string)
}
```

1. str_replace takes ***$bad*** as the ***find*** argument, finding any matching strings from the array.
2. str_replace takes ***""*** as the ***replace*** argument, replacing any found strings with nothing "".
3. str_replace takes ***$string*** as the ***string*** argument, which is the string that will be checked for any matches from the ***find*** argument.

Thus "cleaning" the ***$string*** passed to it from any ***$bad*** sections.

But as for the comment box you talk of I see no code representing such a box?
What you can do is echo your results after each use of your ***clean_string()*** and ensure you get the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. The Comments box is actually the $demowhat = POST(message). I'm just trying to under what this code exactly does

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

and how does it clean?

Comment: @Shang oh Okay that is quite simple, **$bad** is an array of strings it does not return anything as it in itself is a value being: "content-type", "bcc", and so forth, Passing this array into **str_replace(_search_, _replace_, _string_)** as **str_replace(_$bad_,"",$string)** will replace any of the strings found in the **$string** variable from **$bad** with **""** in this case which is nothing. Thus cleaning the string from any **$bad** characters/strings.